# python (pandas) creating a new column based on values from different rows

Tags: python, pandas, function, rows

I have a data frame from a cvs file looking like this:

```
     #F      E    G
0     1  n.e.   153
1     1     60   15
2     1     99   10
3     1      S   23
4     2  n.e.   190
5     2     60   44
6     2     99   22
7     2      S   67
```

I would like to add a new column to this.

For every [#F] group, the [G] value in each row should be divided by the [G]-value in the row where [E]='n.e.' 
So, in the end, it should look like this:

```
     #F      E    G     rel
0     1  n.e.   153   1.000
1     1     60   15   0.098
2     1     99   10   0.065
3     1      S   23   0.150
4     2  n.e.   190   1.000
5     2     60   44   0.232
6     2     99   22   0.116
7     2      S   67   0.353
```

I have tried several approaches using a function, groups or np.where but the problem is a bit more complicated than what I have experience in and nothing works out in the end.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is the row with n.e. guaranteed to be the first row of each group?

Comment: unfortunately no, and the groups might also be larger or smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html).
Creating a series with the corresponding value of `n.e.` for each group using [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html).

> **Note that `first`, omit the `NaN` values, so the position of the `.ne.` value in the group does not matter.** We could also use `max` instead `first`.

```
df['Rel']=df['G'].div(df['G'].where(df['E'].eq('n.e.'))
                             .groupby(df['#F']).transform('first'))
print(df)
  #F     E    G       Rel
0  1  n.e.  153  1.000000
1  1    60   15  0.098039
2  1    99   10  0.065359
3  1     S   23  0.150327
4  2  n.e.  190  1.000000
5  2    60   44  0.231579
6  2    99   22  0.115789
7  2     S   67  0.352632
```

**EDIT**

```
df['Rel']=df['G'].div(df['G'].where(df['E'].eq('n.e. '))
                             .groupby(df['#F']).transform('first'))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I must be missing something. I am getting a column of NaN values anyway with your method.

Comment: I think the problem is that your value is `n.e. `and I am usign `n.e.`.Check section EDIT

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `transform`

```
df['Rel']=df.G/df.groupby(['name','#F']).G.transform('max')
df
   name  #F     E    G       Rel
0  T.w.   1  n.e.  153  1.000000
1  T.w.   1    60   15  0.098039
2  T.w.   1    99   10  0.065359
3  T.w.   1     S   23  0.150327
4  T.w.   2  n.e.  190  1.000000
5  T.w.   2    60   44  0.231579
6  T.w.   2    99   22  0.115789
7  T.w.   2     S   67  0.352632
```

method two

```
s=df.loc[df.E.eq('n.e.')].set_index(['name', '#F']).G.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['name', '#F']])).values
df['Rel']=df.G/s
```

Or

```
df['Rel']=df.G/df.G.mul(df.E.eq('n.e.')).groupby([df['name'],df['#F']]).transform('max')
df
   name  #F     E    G       Rel
0  T.w.   1  n.e.  153  1.000000
1  T.w.   1    60   15  0.098039
2  T.w.   1    99   10  0.065359
3  T.w.   1     S   23  0.150327
4  T.w.   2  n.e.  190  1.000000
5  T.w.   2    60   44  0.231579
6  T.w.   2    99   22  0.115789
7  T.w.   2     S   67  0.352632
```

Comment: Thank you. But this will only work if G is also the maximum at E=n.e., right?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but only your first method worked for me in the example df. The second gave me NaN the other inf values in the new column

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['E'] == 'n.e.', 'G_ne'] = df['G']
df['G_ne'] = df['G_ne'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['rel'] = df['G'] / df['G_ne']

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   #F     E    G   G_ne       rel
0   1  n.e.  153  153.0  1.000000
1   1    60   15  153.0  0.098039
2   1    99   10  153.0  0.065359
3   1     S   23  153.0  0.150327
4   2  n.e.  190  190.0  1.000000
5   2    60   44  190.0  0.231579
6   2    99   22  190.0  0.115789
7   2     S   67  190.0  0.352632
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I must be missing something. I am getting two columns of NaN values with your method